# Хочу шампанское или хочу шампанского — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Интересует, как правильно говорить: хочу шампанск**ого** или хочу шампанск**ое**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В большинстве случаев  говорят "**хочу шампанского**", это Р.п. существительных с вещественным значением при указании на количество, т.е. для обозначения части целого (хочу воды, конфет и др.)

Примеры:

Знойный поцелуй за бутылку шампанского. Серьёзно, ребята, **хочу шампанского**! ― Я съезжу! ― крикнул Кянукук и побежал к мотоциклу. [Василий Аксенов. Пора, мой друг, пора (1963)]

В полусне произнесла протяжно: ― Тоша… **Хочу шампанского!** У нас же с тобой романтический вечер. [Анатолий Приставкин. Вагончик мой дальний (2005)]

Вариант "хочу шампанское" может быть ответом на вопрос: "Ты какое предпочитаешь вино, сухое красное или шампанское?"

Answer (score 2):

Толковый словарь [Ушакова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1082794/%D0%A5%D0%9E%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%AC):
**хотеть**
1. ***кого-чего***, с инф. и без доп. Иметь желание, охоту, ощущать потребность в чем-нибудь.
Хотеть чаю. Хочу хлеба. Хотеть ласки.
[Только родительный падеж.]

Большой [толковый словарь](http://m.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x):
ХОТЕТЬ, хочу; *нсв*.
1. ***кого-чего и что***, с инф.
Иметь желание, намерение (делать что-л.); испытывать потребность, необходимость в ком-либо, в чём-либо.
Х. сладенького. Х. славы, любви, поклонения. Х. машину, дачу.

Управление в русском языке:
ХОТЕТЬ **чего / что (при конкретизации объекта)**.
Хочешь золота или жемчугу? (Р. п.); Хочу новейшее издание справочника (В. п.).

Чаще всего все-таки используется родительный падеж:
— Хочу шампанского! — вновь требовала она (В. Маканин);
— Даня! Я хочу шампанского! Где вы его прячете? (М. Южина);
– Я так хочу шампанского, словно умираю! (Э. Вюрм)

Как же распознать эту "конкретную конкретизацию", чтобы не ошибиться?
Некоторые объяснения даны в статье "[Хотеть и ждать: чего или что?](https://rg.ru/2016/10/06/marina-koroleva-kak-pravilno-hotet-i-zhdat.html) "

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите его абстрактно, в неопределённом количестве (напр. чтобы вас им угостили или где-то срочно достали) или чисто риторически (надежды нет, но вдруг захотелось) то *шампанск**ого***.

*В очень редких случаях*, когда речь идёт о выборе бокала именно с шампанским на подносе, шампанское становится "штучным" предметом, и вы, имея в виду бокал с ним, можете ответить на вопрос "*что из этого вы хотите?*": "*хочу шампанск**ое**... и вот эту клубнику*".